# How to Display Direction list on Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yq0LN.png)

When using directions in Google Maps
I would like to display a list of multiple paths using the api, like the red box in the attached photo, but I do not seem to have a good guide to look for the api document.
I want to know how to implement it.
I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When asking questions, as per the [ask] guide, you should show what you have tried and try to pinpoint exactly what it is you are struggling with. Are you wanting someone to find the API for you? Do you need to know what javascript code implements it? Where have you already tried to find help before asking the question? Keeping these things in mind will help you build more complete questions, and those are questions that are most likely to be answered. Also see [mcve] for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty complicated endeavor to simply have someone walk you through without having built your own code.  That said the I would recomend reading through the [google resource manual](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions).  And here is a walkthrough once you understand some basics of google maps javascript control.

[tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W0juXNFLd6w)

There are free resources to figure it out.  Though there are even better paid resources.  Just check out Udemy for a 10$ course (you have to sign in and search a coupon, but you can get access to any great course for $10)

Give it a shot and get back to us when you have tried some stuff specifically.

Comment: Or is it specifically the box listing direction that you want?